# よみに・よむのに・よむために difference

Tags: grammar, word-choice

よみに・よむことに・よむために

> **よみ**に家にかえる。    　
> **よむの**に家にかえる。　　
> **よむため**に家にかえる。

What is the difference between the above? 
What best fits the English translation "I will go home to read"? 
Please explain why and when each applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence and the last sentence makes perfect sense to me it is basically saying that the person will return back home to read. However the second sentence is going over my head but it could possibly mean the same thing as the other sentences. I'm just confused on the Noni part of the sentence.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Japanese SE. The answer box should only be used to write answers in. This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now, also the 'noni' sentence was solely experimental,

Answer (score -1):

> よみに家にかえる。 　
> よむのに家にかえる。　
> よむために家にかえる。

Sentences have the same fundamental meaning although differ in formality,
Bottom sentence being formal and top being informal,